# Deploy and start a windows service on remote machine using Gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, yaml, windows-services, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I started using Gitlab CI/CD and it is my `yml` file:

```
variables:
 EXE_LOCAL_TEMP_FOLDER: 'c:\TMP'
 DEPLOY_FOLDER: 'c:\MyProject_Release'

stages:
- build
- deploy

build:
   stage: build
   script:
    - nuget restore
    - msbuild MySolution.sln /t:Build  /p:Configuration=Release
    - xcopy /y MyProject\bin\Release\*.* $EXE_LOCAL_TEMP_FOLDER\
deploy:
   stage: deploy
   when : manual
   script:
     - xcopy /y c:\TMP\*.* $DEPLOY_FOLDER\
```

Now I need to deploy a Windows Service(`WinService.csproj` in my solution) on a remote machine, How can I do it in my `yml` file?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you install your runner on local machine joined at your local domain. You can use sc \\machine  stop  <yourservice>  and  sc \\machine start <yourservice> to update your service.